# is there a solution to run cron job command in cpanel only from my cPanel host?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, jobs

I have a Laravel store script. I wrote a plugin for this script that makes a backup from the database.
I have routed it with the following command:

```
Route::get('/backupsfiles/cronbackup', [BackupFilesController::class,'cronbackup'])->name('backupsfiles.cronbackup');
```

And I have created a cron job with the following command in cPanel:

```
wget -O - http://subdomain.domain.com/backupsfiles/cronbackup
```

If I execute this command from the terminal environment of my computer that has Linux operating system, this script will be executed.
But the problem is that I want this script to be executed only from my cPanel host and no one else can execute it from another Linux terminal.
In addition, there are other functions in the **BackupFilesController** file that even guest users can use without logging in. For example, if a backup file has been shared, they can download it without logging in.
Is there a solution?
thanks in advance

Comment: What prevents you removing that route? Have you tried using a command instead?

Comment: Thank you. I think it's a good idea to use a method other than routing, but I'm not familiar with it
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's in the [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/artisan#writing-commands "Writing Commands -- In addition to the commands provided with Artisan, you may build your own custom commands."). See the version switch there.